# Книга электронная и книга "живая"

Tags: общие-вопросы

Вопрос не совсем по русскому языку, но, думаю, что его все-таки уместно тут задать. А касается он несмолкаемых споров о том, что лучше: книга в электронном виде в компьютере или "читалке" или "живая", бумажная книга? 
Многие мне доказывают, что бумажные книги свое отжили, что будущее за электронными носителями, что в "читалку" входит целая библиотека, а бумажные книги дороги и, по выражению моего знакомого, "сборщики пыли".
Да, я согласна, что книги сейчас дороги. Уже десять раз подумаешь, прежде чем что-то купить. Кроме того, в интернете выложено много неизданных талантливых произведений. Да и в 
"читалку" загрузил, не понравилось — стер.
Но бумажная книга... Вопреки всем доводам разума я их больше люблю. А вы что скажете? За чем будущее?

Answer (score 10):

Как с возникновением телевидения не умер театр, так и с возникновением электронной книги не исчезнет книга бумажная.

Читать люблю. Поэтому купила электронную книгу, и теперь в электричке (часто приходится ездить) есть выбор, читаю, что хочется, а не то, что есть. Загрузила много справочной литературы, теперь она всегда под рукой. Скачала книги, на которые не хватает денег, читаю. В общем, я привыкла к электронной книжке. Но бумажная книга роднее, привычнее, любимее. Да и многие жанры гораздо интереснее читать на бумаге. Книги по искусству на хорошей глянцевой бумаге. Учебники с таблицами и схемами. Стихи почему-то приятнее читать именно в бумажном варианте.

Замечательно, что теперь есть выбор. Я думаю, жить будут и электронные книги (несомненно, они будут совершенствоваться), и традиционные, изданные на бумаге.

Comment: Да, у меня тоже есть электронная книга, и это действительно удобно, особенно, когда хочется прочитать что-то неизданное. Но живые книги - есть живые книги.

Answer (score 4):

Тут два вопроса.

1. Бумажная книга лучше в сто раз.
2. Будущее - за электронной.

Это вопрос экономики и технологии: разница в стоимости между электронными и бумажными книгами будет постоянно расти, а по удобству и приятности в обращении - сокращаться. Бумажные книги в итоге останутся у отдельных счастливцев в качестве дорогих раритетов.

Comment: Увы, разница уже существенная((( Раньше я могла на книжном рынке купить книгу просто потому, что мне понравилась аннотация. А сейчас сорок раз задумаешься, ибо цены мягко говоря кусаются.

Answer (score 4):

Для того чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос, нужно сперва решить, а что же такое бумажная книга для читателя.

1. Носитель печатного текста.
2. Статусный объект.
3. Носитель графической информации (рисунки, репродукции, схемы, графики).
4. Груз в багаже при поездке.
5. Объект для хранения.

Как носитель текста и объект хранения, электронная книга уже по всем статьям превосходит книгу бумажную.

Как носитель информации графической и груз в багаже, пока пожалуй равенство, но в будущем без сомнения начнётся доминирование цифры над бумагой.

Но статусным объектом электронная книга не станет никогда. Поэтому судьба бумажной книги будет примерно такой же как судьба грампластинок в современности, дорогие, немногим нужные статусные объекты, для истинных гурманов музыки (чтения).

Answer (score 1):

Почему-то все забывают, что все-таки существует разница - читать книгу или читать с экрана с т.з. полезности для здоровья. Известно, что человеческий глаз лучше всего воспринимает отраженный свет от объектов - это нормальное положение вещей. На источники освещения смотреть можно, но это неприятно. До изобретения "электронных чернил" все экраны, используемые в планшетах и компьютерах, содержали встроенный источник освещения. Так что неудивительно, что после того, как посидишь перед компьютером целый день, глаза начинают болеть или сильно уставать. Так что даешь нормальные читалки в массы =) Естественно, когда технологию сделают более обкатанной (дешевой, надежной, удобной, подставить свои критерии).

Касательно спора что лучше - каждый выбирает для себя. Плюсы и минусы есть у обоих вариантов. Мне лично пока бумажная книга удобнее. В частности, если речь идет об учебниках и художественной литературе. Техническую литературу и документацию я вполне спокойно читаю и с экрана компьютера, и с экрана "читалки". А газеты так я вообще уже не читаю, смотрю новости в онлайне - тут Интернет без сомнения победил.

Answer (score 0):

Хочется верить, что у нас бумажная книга останется столь же востребованной, как и ранее. Иначе нас может ожидать та же печальная ситуация, что и на западе, где бумажная книга стоит ОЧЕНЬ больших денег. А некоторые и вовсе стоят нереально больших сумм, хотя это уже ситуация рукописей (вот тут было интересно видео на тему https://www.investory.pro/ru/video/book). Хотя у нас ситуация уже стала значительно хуже.

Comment: Так будущее за дорогостоящей рукописью?